# Is it possible to use UIStoryBoard in a different UIStoryBoard's UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I want to divide my flows in a separate storyboards.
At this point, i have created my main storyboard which is side menu.

What i want to do is, when a menu item is pressed i want to be loaded from another storyboard inside the main view controller view.

Is it possible, if yes,

How to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

To initiate a view controller from a storyboard named @"myStoryboard", and if you are using Restoration ID to create your controllers, you can do :

```
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerID"];
```

(of course, @"ControllerID" refers to the ID you've set for your controller in the storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a storyboard for any part of a program. Storyboards are not an all or nothing concept. You can have just one view controller in a storyboard, or a small network that just represents a subsection of your app.

**To use just one view controller from a storyboard:**

Add a new storyboard to your existing project.

Add a single view controller to the storyboard.

Assign an identifier to the view controller in the inspector.

Use the UIStoryboard class to load the storyboard resource

Use -`[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]` to create a new instance of that view controller.

Install the view controller some place in your app by doing something like pushing it on to a navigation controller, or run it modally.

Author:Jon Hess

Comment: the confusing part for me is to install the view controller some place in my app by doing...